# How to get file size of all datasets of data factory - specially data lake store and blob?

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

We have many different pipelines in Azure data factory with many data sets. Mainly we have data sets of Azure data lake store and Azure Blobs. I want to know the file size of all files (from all datasets of all pipelines). I am able to iterate all the datasets from all the pipeline using DataFactoryManagementClient in C# but when I am trying to see fileName or folderName of the dataset, I am getting null. You can see my below code -

private static void GetDataSetSize(DataFactoryManagementClient dataFactoryManagementClient)
        {
            string resourceGroupName = "resourceGroupName";

```
        foreach (var dataFactory in dataFactoryManagementClient.DataFactories.List(resourceGroupName).DataFactories)
        {
            var linkedServices = new List<LinkedService>(dataFactoryManagementClient.LinkedServices.List(resourceGroupName, dataFactory.Name).LinkedServices);
            var datasets = dataFactoryManagementClient.Datasets.List(resourceGroupName, dataFactory.Name).Datasets;

            foreach (var dataset in datasets)
            {

                var lsTypeProperties = linkedServices.First(ls => ls.Name == dataset.Properties.LinkedServiceName).Properties.TypeProperties;

                if(lsTypeProperties.GetType() == typeof(AzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService))//AzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService))
                {
                    AzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService outputLinkedService = lsTypeProperties as AzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService;
                    var folder = GetBlobFolderPathDL(dataset);
                    var file = GetBlobFileNameDL(dataset);

                }
            }

        }
    }
    public static string GetBlobFolderPathDL(Dataset dataset)
    {
        if (dataset == null || dataset.Properties == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        AzureDataLakeStoreDataset dlDataset = dataset.Properties.TypeProperties as AzureDataLakeStoreDataset;
        if (dlDataset == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return dlDataset.FolderPath;
    }

    public static string GetBlobFileNameDL(Dataset dataset)
    {
        if (dataset == null || dataset.Properties == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        AzureDataLakeStoreDataset dlDataset = dataset.Properties.TypeProperties as AzureDataLakeStoreDataset;
        if (dlDataset == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return dlDataset.FileName;
    }
```

With this, I want to generate monitoring tool which will tell me how data is increasing for each file/dataset?

FYI - I am going to monitor retries, failures of each slice. I can get this information without any issue, but now the problem is about getting the file name and folder path because it's returning me null(It seems to be a bug in API). Once I have folder and file path, then using DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient I will get the file size of those files.  I am planning to ingest all this data (size, fileName, retries, failure etc) into SQL database and on top of it - I will generate reports which will tell me how my data is growing daily or hourly etc.

I want to make it generic, in such a way that - if in future I add new dataset or pipeline - I get the size of all newly added datasets also without changing any code.

Please help me how can I achieve this.  Suggest me if there is an alternate way if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place this code in your main method and execute.You may able to see your datasets folderpath and filenames.Use this and change accordingly to your requirement.

**Hope this helps!**

```
         foreach (var dataFactory in dataFactoryManagementClient.DataFactories.List(resourceGroupName).DataFactories)
    {
     var datasets = dataFactoryManagementClient.Datasets.List(resourceGroupName, dataFactory.Name).Datasets;
        foreach (var dataset in datasets)
        {

            var lsTypeProperties = dataFactoryManagementClient.Datasets.Get(resourceGroupName,dataFactory.Name,dataset.Name);

            if (lsTypeProperties.Dataset.Properties.TypeProperties.GetType() == typeof(AzureDataLakeStoreDataset))//AzureDataLakeStoreDataset))
            {
                AzureDataLakeStoreDataset OutputDataSet = lsTypeProperties.Dataset.Properties.TypeProperties as AzureDataLakeStoreDataset;
                Console.WriteLine(OutputDataSet.FolderPath);
                Console.WriteLine(OutputDataSet.FileName);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

    }
```